# How to Create a Javafx Image Slider using the ImageView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to create an image slider. i have the image view and the static images. How can i fade out with transition changing the images along with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please use my simple below code of image slider with button or without button.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageSliderDemo extends Application {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int j = 0;
    double orgCliskSceneX, orgReleaseSceneX;
    Button lbutton, rButton;
    ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // images in src folder.
    try {
        list.add("/1.jpg");
        list.add("/1.png");
        list.add("/12.png");
        list.add("/13.png");
        list.add("/2.jpg");
        list.add("/2.png");
        list.add("/3.jpg");
        list.add("/4.png");
        list.add("/a.jpg");
        list.add("/Logo.png");

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        lbutton = new Button("<");
        rButton = new Button(">");

        Image images[] = new Image[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            images[i] = new Image(list.get(i));
        }

        imageView = new ImageView(images[j]);
        imageView.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);

        imageView.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedEventHandler);

        imageView.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            orgReleaseSceneX = e.getSceneX();
            if (orgCliskSceneX > orgReleaseSceneX) {
                lbutton.fire();
            } else {
                rButton.fire();
            }
        });

        rButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            j = j + 1;
            if (j == list.size()) {
                j = 0;
            }
            imageView.setImage(images[j]);

        });
        lbutton.setOnAction(e -> {
            j = j - 1;
            if (j == 0 || j > list.size() + 1 || j == -1) {
                j = list.size() - 1;
            }
            imageView.setImage(images[j]);

        });

        imageView.setFitHeight(100);
        imageView.setFitWidth(300);

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(15);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        // hBox.getChildren().addAll(lbutton, imageView, rButton);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(imageView);

        root.add(hBox, 1, 1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        orgCliskSceneX = t.getSceneX();
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```